# Linear $L:X\to Y$ and $\forall f\in Y^{*}$ we have $f\circ L\in X^{*}$, then L is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

X,Y is Banach , $L:X\to Y$ is linear and $\forall f\in Y^{*}$ we have $f\circ L\in X^{*}$, then L is bounded.

The hint is to use closed graph theorem.

Attempt
Take a converging sequence $x_{n}\in x$. WTS $L(x_{n})\to L(x)$.

So $f\circ L(x_{n})\to f\circ L(x)$. Then maybe use projections...

any ideas

Comment: Let $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Lx_n \rightarrow y$. Compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} (f\circ L)(x_n)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f (Lx_n)$. Use this to show $Lx=y$.

Comment: we don't know if f is injective.

Comment: we don't know even know that $Lx_{n}\to y$.

Comment: It's the definition of a closed operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators

Comment: i don't think you understand. From f being closed you get $f(y)=f(L(x_{n})$. But $f(y)=f(L(x_{n})$  implies $y=L(x_{n}$ only if f is injective.

Comment: But we don't even know that $L(x_{n})$ converges.

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, the closed graph theorem says that if an operator $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is closed, then $L$ is continuous. An operator $L$ is *closed* when the following holds: $$x_n\rightarrow x \text{ and } Lx_n\rightarrow y \implies Lx=y  $$

So let $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $Lx_n\rightarrow y$. For all $f\in Y^*$ we have by continuity: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(Lx_n)=f(y)$$

and since $f\circ L\in X^*$, we also have: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (f\circ L)(x_n)=(f\circ L)(x)=f(Lx)$$

Now, suppose $Lx\neq y$. Then the Hahn-Banach theorem implies the existence of a functional $y^*\in Y^*$ such that $y^*(Lx)\neq y^*(y)$. This is a contradiction, since we showed above that $f(y) = f(Lx)$ for all $f\in Y^*$, so we must have $Lx=y$.

**Edit:** For the version of Hahn-Banach that I used see Rudin, Functional Analysis, Chapter 3. He proves that for all $x\in X$, there exists a functional $x^* \in X^*$, such that $x^*(x)=\|x\|$. Now, if $x_1\neq x_2$, we obtain a functional $x^*$ such that $x^*(x_1-x_2)=\|x_1-x_2\|\neq 0.$ This means that $x^*(x_1)\neq x^*(x_2)$.

Comment: @TKM To apply the closed graph theorem, you only have to show that if $(Lx_n)$ converges to $y$, then $Lx=y$.

Comment: @TKM I edited for clarification